# How to change "text/plain" to xml?

Tags: text, wso2

My Endpoint is a Address Endpoint. The response contentType is "text/plain". And the reponse content is:

```
<message>
   <header>
      <TransactionID>1</TransactionID>
      <Timestamp>2012-06-04 10:45:35</Timestamp>
      <OpCode>AAA_Response</OpCode>
      <MsgType>RESP</MsgType>
      <ReturnCode>1007</ReturnCode>
      <ErrorMessage/>
   </header>
   <body/>
</message>
```

But in the wso2, the response changed to:

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;message&gt;&lt;header&gt;&lt;TransactionID&gt;1&lt;/TransactionID&gt;&lt;Timestamp&gt;2012-06-04 10:45:35&lt;/Timestamp&gt;&lt;OpCode&gt;AAA_Response&lt;/OpCode&gt;&lt;MsgType&gt;RESP&lt;/MsgType&gt;&lt;ReturnCode&gt;1007&lt;/ReturnCode&gt;&lt;ErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/ErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/header&gt;&lt;body/&gt;&lt;/message&gt;
</text>
```

I think I need edited builder and formatter in axis2.xml. But how to do this? Anyone can help me? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't set up the appropriate builder and formatter in axis2.xml.

Set org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder for content type text/plain

Comment: I have tried to set builder and formatter, but failed. Can you tell me how to set this in ESB4.0.3, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the server-side first, if possible.

Comment: No, I can not do this. Service can not be change. Thanks for your advise